# Parse web application credentials and sending push to different credentials

Tags: javascript, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm creating a web application and use Parse to manage users, I use my Parse applicationID and JavaScriptId.

```
Parse.initialize("my-app-id", "my-js-id");
Parse.User.logIn(username, password,...
```

When the user login to the site, he/she enter their Parse app-id and js-Id that belong to their mobile app that they want to push a notification to. And the website send notification to them:

```
Parse.initialize("their-android-app-id", "their-android-js-id");
Parse.Push.send({ where: new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation), data: ...
```

I'm not clear when to call initialize and how I distinguish between my javascript app and the android/iOS app that I want to send to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as i know it isn't possible to use the same api with two diffrent api-keys. I think it would be the most easiest way to use the normal JavaScript-API for application A, but the REST-API for application B, since you only need to send push notifications for the application B.

In JQuery this could look for example like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/push',
     type: 'post',
     data: {
         where : {
             ...
         },
         data : {
             ...
         }
     },
     headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": "their-app-id",
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "their-rest-api-key",
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //data: response data from the Parse.com REST-API
    }
});
```

A quide from Parse about how to use push notifications through the REST-API is available [here.](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/REST)